Несколько методов в одном классе
Здравствуйте Уважаемые программисты!
Есть код c# vs 2022:
namespace LayoutDocument
{
    public partial class LayoutsDocument
    {
        [Teigha.Runtime.CommandMethod("LayoutDocA1")]
        public void LayoutDocumentA1()
        {

        }

    }
}

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать несколько "CommandMethod", т.е. еще "LayoutDocA2", "LayoutDocA3" и т.д.?
Заранее спасибо!

Я не эксперт по C#, но вот в статейке вполне себе два метода сосуществуют в рамках одного класса.

Спасибо, попробую!
